# Comparing means and medians (with different dispersion indeces) from different studies

Tags: mean, median, dispersion, systematic-review

I'm doing a systematic search and I have a pool of articles that for each outcome report different central values (mean and median) and dispersion indices (SD, 95% CI, IQR). Is there a statistical test that I can get to a value that describes each variable? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

While there are statistical tests that can be run with meta-level data such as this, it seems that you want to summarize the measured effect for something over a number of research articles and reports.  Thus, you are asking to do a meta-analysis.

There is a large body of research on meta-analysis that you can draw from in order to accomplish this.  In brief, there often is a challenge exactly as you describe in attempting this.  Here, you want to try to describe the central tendency (say the mean of the population), but you have different measures of center from different reports.  Likewise for the variability of the population.

Without going into too much detail, one strategy that you can use is to record the mean and/or median as the dependent variable in your meta-analysis data collection.  But, you will also want to have another variable in the data set to record if it was reported as the mean or median (or something else).  Same will need to be done for the measures of spread you record.

Once you have this, you can then transform the estimates into a common metric.  For example, you can divide the IQR by about 4/3 to get the SD.

One final comment is that you want to make sure you are collecting as much additional information from each of the published reports as is reasonably possible, as this will allow a more detailed analysis of the final meta-analysis model.  The key here is to be as transparent in everything so future researchers can assess potential concerns form the estimates your research reports.

Comment: Thank you very much Greg, your help is very valuable for me. So, once I have collected all the central values and dispersion indeces of all the variables, which kind of program you would suggest to use? I have SPSS and RevMan. Shall I use one of these? And which function you would advice to use? Thank you so much

Comment: Fabio_Carbone posted this as an "answer" (instead of comment)
Thank you very much Greg, your help is very valuable for me. So, once I have collected all the central values and dispersion indeces of all the variables, which kind of program you would suggest to use? I have SPSS and RevMan. Shall I use one of these? And which function you would advice to use? Thank you so much

Comment: @Fabio_Carbone I would suggest SPSS or even better to just use R.  There are a number of useful textbooks available that can provide specific instruction using either.  But, the first step is to collect the data in a database file for each report your are examining...and probably best to just use Excel or Google Sheets for this

Comment: Thank you very much Gregg. Yes I already collected them in an excel sheet. I collected the central value and uncertainty i any cell. Now I would like to calculate a unique value for each variable. E.g. I have for a same variable some numbers expressed as mean (SD), some in median (min-max) and some in median (IQR). How can I calculate something? Which function shall I use in spss? Thank you so much!

Comment: For the median IQR, I would estimate the SD as $\frac{Q_3-q_1}{4/3}$.  You can use a more precise value for the denominator, e.g., 2*qnorm(0.75) = 1.34898, but all in all, this would be more than sufficient for an estimate for a meta-analysis.  I'd have to think more on the min-max estimates.  I would recommend checking a textbook on meta-analysis to assist further in what you should do with this data.